# What's the difference between S32 VS U32?

Tags: python

In python, what's the difference between S and U datatype? Can't find the documentation. Both are string types. Right?

Comment: What exactly are you talking about? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I am seeing "S32", "U10" data type for some code in my command line interpreter. I guess both are 'string' types. But can't find any documentation.

Comment: I understand that you are seeing this, but we are not. Please show us.

Comment: Are you using Numpy by chance?

Comment: Ye. I am using numpy array. np.array(...)

Comment: @user697911 Then I believe I have an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What your probably referring to are the `S32` and `U32` data types of Numpy arrays. They specfic to Numpy, and are not built in to Python.

To answer your question, the difference between the two is that if the `dtype` of a Numpy array is `S32`, that means that one of your arrays contain *strings*. While on the other hand, a `dtype` of `U32` means that one of your arrays contains *unicode*.

Comment: Why is it sometimes a simple String, and sometimes its a unicode string?

Comment: @user697911 Because sometimes regular strings are used in the array, and sometimes _unicode_ is used in the array.